# Error in a Laravel Example Api in Post service

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I create a Example API in Laravel and I have a POST services.

This service set me error in the `$request->input('name')`..

In the browser set me this error.

> Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\UserController::createUsers() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request given

I Use this components.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

I using only

```
use Request;
```

But this set me the same error.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Show your UserController code

Answer (score 0):

Can use this component in your controller.

```
use App\Http\Requests;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved.

In public/index.php I put `Request::capture();` instead of `Request::createFromGlobals();`